# Update Store Summary By Checkout Address Country Change

Tags: magento2, module, custom, php-7

So Basically I want to update my checkout cart summary when user select country from shipping address ,cart price and currency change according to the country he selected in shipping address.

Comment: For which version you need this feature magento1 or magento 2?

Comment: For Magento 2.2 @AmitBera

Comment: @XainIjaz, Have you done this?  I have same requirement